# Android ListView getViewAt

Tags: android, android-widget, homescreen

I'm trying to get click event on my `ListView` on homesreen widget.
For this I'm using following code:

```
public class ViewFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
...

  @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
         RemoteViews row=new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.row);
        Log.i("position receive trans", Integer.toString(position));

        row.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text1, items[position]);
        Intent i = new Intent(this.ctxt, AppWidget.class);
        i.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_UPDATE_POSITION);
        i.putExtra("position", position);
        row.setOnClickFillInIntent(android.R.id.text1, i);
        return(row);
    }
```

But I'm getting this event not only after clicking on widget. I'm getting this also after adding widget to the home screen.

Is there any way to determine different actions (Click and adding to homescreen?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such situation can be determined by
`intent.getAction()`;
For enabling widget is : `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED`
For updatewidget is : `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE`